# Raspberry Pi: After unplugging, red Ligh on, and green light does not blink. Device won't boot

Tags: raspberry-pi

Using Raspberry Pi 1 Model B, it was working ok, but this morning I switched it off (by unplugging the energy source). When switching it on again, the red power LED is on, the green light does not blink, and the device does not boot.

The SD card is connected and the rest of components (a USB WiFi, and a USB pendrive). I have checked the troubleshooting of
http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_on.2C_green_LED_does_not_flash.2C_nothing_on_display
but none of the issues seems to work.

Any similar experiences are welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you shut it down correctly or just kill the power to the device?

Comment: Most probably sd-card got corrupted.